# Instead of typing up a bunch of "Or" statements, how can I implement a function in this code?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, boolean-logic

```
Sub test()

Dim DataRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim SplitVal() As String
Dim OutputOffset As Long
OutputOffset = 0

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If InStr(1, Cells(i, 10).Value, "Test1", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Or 
       InStr(1, Cells(i, 10).Value, "Test2", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Or 
       InStr(1, Cells(i, 10).Value, "Test3", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then

      SplitVal = Split(Cells(i - 2, 10).Value, " ", 2)
      Cells(i + OutputOffset, 13).Value = SplitVal(0)
      Cells(i + OutputOffset, 14).Value = SplitVal(1)

      Cells(i + OutputOffset, 15).Value = Cells(i + 1, 10).Value
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Hey everyone. So as you can see my code goes through and checks for Test1,Test2,or Test3. Problem is I have 50+ accounts I need checking not 3!

How do I create and populate a list, make a function that replicates what I have above, and iterate the list using the function?

Thanks so much everyone!

Comment: [Select case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx)?  But using your specific example, are you looking for anything that starts with `Test`? Or perhaps you're looking for all tests except a type, and "reverse" it?  It'd help if you could expand a little on the accounts, and if there's a pattern there at all.

Comment: @BruceWayne  Well I'm very new to programming in general, is it difficult to implement that kindof logic? My real dataset, replace "test" with company names. I have a giant list and need to pull the data from 50+ companies

Comment: You need to make a unique array from company names and check if the cell value is within the array.

Comment: @Masoud could you show me the code you used?

Comment: @MikeMcoei I have not used the code below, but that's what I would do for this purpose.

Comment: @Masoud - Isn't it '*check if each array element is within the cell value*' or have I got the Instr parameters backwards?

Comment: @Jeeped not sure if exactly got what you mean, but I think you got it wrong.

Comment: @Masoud - You stated '*check if the cell value is within the array*' ; from that I infer direct comparison. Instr is '*substring within a string*'.

Comment: @Jeeped Got you now. You are right but that was just a raw idea that how an answer can be implemented. Let me see if I still can edit that. (Unfortunately I cannot)

Comment: @MikeMcoei, do you read your company names from some excel range or do you have them already in some array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build an array of the 50 possibles to loop through. Exit the loop as soon as one is found.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SplitVal() As String
    Dim OutputOffset As Long
    Dim v As Long, tests As Variant
    OutputOffset = 0

    tests = Array("Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7", "Test8", "Test9", _
                  "Test10", "Test11", "Test12", "Test13", "Test14", "Test15", "Test16", "Test17", "Test18", _
                  "Test19", "Test20", "Test21", "Test22", "Test23", "Test24", "Test25", "Test26", "Test27")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            For v = LBound(tests) To UBound(tests)
                If CBool(InStr(1, .Cells(i, 10).Value2, tests(v), vbTextCompare)) Then Exit For
            Next v

            If v <= UBound(tests) Then
                SplitVal = Split(.Cells(i - 2, 10).Value2, " ", 2)
                .Cells(i + OutputOffset, 13).Value = SplitVal(0)
                .Cells(i + OutputOffset, 14).Value = SplitVal(1)
                .Cells(i + OutputOffset, 15).Value2 = .Cells(i + 1, 10).Value2
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

I've added in some parent worksheet references.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 4):

That's a concern of its own; it belongs in its own scope. I use a function like this for short-circuiting otherwise redundant conditions - `ParamArray` is the secret sauce here:

```
Public Function MatchesAny(ByVal needle As String, ParamArray haystack() As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim found As Boolean

    For i = LBound(haystack) To UBound(haystack)
        found = (needle = CStr(haystack(i)))            
        If found Then Exit For
    Next

    MatchesAny = found

End Function
```

That would be used like this:

```
If MatchesAny(CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value), _
    "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", _
    "Test6", "Test7", "Test8", "Test9", "Test10", _
    "Test11", "Test12", "Test13", ..., "Test50") _
Then
    'match was found
End If
```

You can quite easily tweak the `haystack` to support passing a 1D array of values like [@Jeeped's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43196218/1188513); the principle is the same: bail out as soon as you know your result; your current code will execute every single `InStr` statement, even if the first Boolean expression to be evaluated is `True`.

That function returns `True` if any item *matches* the specified string. Sometimes you might need a function that returns `True` if any item *contains* the specified string. That's another function:

```
Public Function ContainsAny(ByVal needle As String, ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean, ParamArray haystack() As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim found As Boolean

    For i = LBound(haystack) To UBound(haystack)
        found = Contains(needle, CStr(haystack(i)), caseSensitive)            
        If found Then Exit For
    Next

    ContainsAny = found

End Function
```

This one calls a simple wrapper function around `InStr`, which helps improve the readability of `InStr() <> 0` calls:

```
Public Function Contains(ByVal needle As String, ByVal haystack As String, Optional ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    Dim compareMethod As VbCompareMethod

    If caseSensitive Then
        compareMethod = vbBinaryCompare
    Else
        compareMethod = vbTextCompare
    End If

    Contains = (InStr(1, haystack, needle, compareMethod) <> 0)

End Function
```

Usage of that one is similar, except we have a `caseSensitive` parameter that needs to be specified (you might want to tweak `MatchesAny` to have a similar signature) before the list of arguments. Again, same principle: bail out as soon as you know what to return.

Comment: Thank you. Let me ask around to see how I can implement the code you gave me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your 50 accounts are probably in a list which is available in your worksheet. You can create a strong of those accounts and use the `instr` function to find if there is a match.

```
    Sub test()

        Dim DataRange As Range
        Dim LastRow As Integer
        Dim i As Long
        Dim SplitVal() As String
        Dim OutputOffset As Long
        OutputOffset = 0

        Dim Spike As String
        For i = 3 To 11
            Spike = Spike & Cells(i, 1).Value & "|"
        Next i

        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRow
            If InStr(Spike, Cells(i, 10).Value) Then
    '        If InStr(1, Cells(i, 10).Value, "Test1", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Or
    '           InStr(1, Cells(i, 10).Value, "Test2", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Or
    '           InStr(1, Cells(i, 10).Value, "Test3", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then

              SplitVal = Split(Cells(i - 2, 10).Value, " ", 2)
              Cells(i + OutputOffset, 13).Value = SplitVal(0)
              Cells(i + OutputOffset, 14).Value = SplitVal(1)

              Cells(i + OutputOffset, 15).Value = Cells(i + 1, 10).Value
            End If
        Next i

End Sub
```

In my example the list is in A3:A11 on the ActiveSheet. If that doesn't work for you, place the list on another sheet and change the above code as follows.

```
Dim WsList As Worksheet
Dim Spike As String
Set WsList = Worksheets("AccountList")
For i = 3 To 11
    Spike = Spike & WsList.Cells(i, 1).Value & "|"
Next i
```