# Trouble getting custom function syntax right: Contains()

Tags: excel, vba, function, contains

I'm desperately trying to implement this solution to my own code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43196497/11632049

The goal is to search for various strings ("ABC", "123", ...) and if a data row contains the string, copy the row to a different workbook.  I am getting a sub or function not defined error

```
Public Function ContainsAny(ByVal needle As String, ByVal caseSensitive As _ 
    Boolean, ParamArray haystack() As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim k As Integer
    Dim found As Boolean

    For k = LBound(haystack) To UBound(haystack)
        found = Contains(needle, CStr(haystack(k)), caseSensitive)
        If found Then Exit For
    Next
    ContainsAny = found

End Function


Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

    Dim CoderBook As Workbook
    Dim Review As Workbook
    Dim Alpha As Worksheet
    Dim Coder As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set CoderBook = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    Set Coder = CoderBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set Review = ThisWorkbook
    Set Alpha = Review.Sheets("Sheet5")

    'Search code
    LastRow = Alpha.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Loop search code
    For i = 2 To LastRow

        If Alpha.Range("G" & i) <> Alpha.Range("H" & i) Or _
        Alpha.Range("J" & i) <> Alpha.Range("K" & i) Then

        Select Case True
        Case ContainsAny(Ophth.Range("H" & i), False, "ABC", "123")

            DuplicateCheck = Application.Match(Alpha.Range("A" & i).Value, _ 
            Coder.Columns(1), 0)
            If IsError(DuplicateCheck) Then
                Coder.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0). _
                EntireRow.Value = Alpha.Rows(i).Value
            End If
        End Select
       End If

    Next i

CoderBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "I can't get it to work" is not a helpful description of your problem. Please provide details of error messages etc.

Comment: Where do you declare `Alpha`, `Coder`, `CoderBook`?  Also, I'm not sure, but can you split this on to separate lines like you do, `...Offset(1, 0).EntireRow...`?  I'd add `Option Explicit` to the *very very top* of your code module, which forces you to declare and define all variables used.  That's likely part of the issue here.

Comment: Adding to the @BruceWayne comment - `CoderBook` and `DuplicateCheck` ?

Comment: @SJR Sorry - when I try to expand the Contains() to be Contains("ABC", "123", ....) it says there's a type mismatch -- Looking at the solution post I'm attempting to implement, I think it has to do with that my function isn't expecting a "ParamArray"... but I'm already at the tail end of my knowledge here

Comment: FYI you could do `Case Alpha.Range("H" & i).Value Like "*ABC*"` instead of using a custom function, if I understand this correctly.

Comment: Perhaps you'd have to do ` Contains("ABC"...)`, ` Contains("123", ....) ` ? Otherwise yes ParamArray would be required.

Comment: @BruceWayne updated to include all of the declarations.  The trouble is, I'm trying to avoid a ton of code duplication to outline all the possible strings that I'm searching for - I'm just testing it right now trying to get it to return for "ABC" & "123" but I'll have about 40 other strings

Comment: Or could have an array of strings and loop through them?

Comment: @SJR I tried implementing this solution which I think loops through an array https://stackoverflow.com/a/43196218/11632049 but I'm just so new to VBA I'm struggling through either solution and I've gotten closer with this one so far

Comment: *when I try to expand the Contains() to be Contains("ABC", "123", ....) it says there's a type mismatch* - that's because the `Contains` function only accepts a single "needle"/"haystack" (depending which string is containing which) parameter. Looks like you want `ContainsAny`, from the same post.

Comment: That would be `ContainsAny(Alpha.Range("H" & i).Value, False, "ABC", "DEF", "XYZ")`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank God you're here!  I am so confused about the haystack() being the ParamArray in your ContainsAny() function.  To be clear, I am needing to see if my Alpha.Range contains any of "ABC", "DEF", etc so I thought that would make my "ABC" "DEF" need to be the paramarray.  So when I look at the 'found = Contains(needle, CStr(haystack(i)), caseSensitive)' it seems to me like I should be putting my "ABC" "DEF" first as needle??

Comment: Think of it as looking for a "needle" in a "haystack" - there's one "needle", and multiple possible strings in the "haystack". Syntactically speaking, only one parameter can be a `ParamArray`, and it has to be the last parameter.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I will edit code in question post for ContainsAny() attempt - I'm getting a "sub or function not defined" error

Comment: Well you need to have the function defined somewhere.. it's invoking the `Contains` function, but you outright replaced it.

Comment: Whether the function can work as-is depends on what the actual data looks like: if `Alpha.Range` is e.g. "foo xyz bar" then some tweaks are in order indeed - perhaps something like `If Not Contains Then Contains = (InStr(1, needle, haystack, compareMethod) <> 0)` after the `Contains = (InStr(1, haystack, needle, compareMethod) <> 0)` assignment, to make it check both ways.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Oh duh, THANK YOU.  It is working now, but also returning rows of data that do not appear to have "ABC" or "123" but I will keep reviewing my syntax

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a "function not defined" compile error because `ContainsAny` is invoking the `Contains` function, which you removed. Add it back.

```
found = Contains(needle, CStr(haystack(k)), caseSensitive)
```

But, the logic of the `Contains` method needs to be flipped for it to work the way you want to use it:

```
Public Function Contains(ByVal needle As String, ByVal haystack As String, Optional ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    Dim compareMethod As VbCompareMethod

    If caseSensitive Then
        compareMethod = vbBinaryCompare
    Else
        compareMethod = vbTextCompare
    End If

    Contains = (InStr(1, haystack, needle, compareMethod) <> 0)
    If Not Contains Then Contains = (InStr(1, needle, haystak, compareMethod) <> 0)

End Function
```

That way `Contains` will return `True` when either string contains the other - and with that you can do:

```
 If ContainsAny(Ophth.Range("H" & i).Value, False, "ABC", "123", "XYZ") Then
```

And the conditional block will execute when the cell value contains any one of the specified strings.

Comment: When I added the new "If not contains then contains = " piece that you featured above, it returned alllll kinds of rows that I don't need.   I just need to know when Alpha.Range contains any of the strings I'm going to list "ABC" "123", "XYZ" etc.  I'm getting confused because I'm used to the InStr() syntax: InStr(Alpha.Range, "ABC") <-- if only I could keep listing "123" "XYZ"

Comment: @maclee it's very hard for me to know what it is that you need exactly, because I have no idea what `Alpha.Range(...).Value` is, or what `ABC`, `XYZ`, `123` placeholder bogus strings actually stand for.

Comment: I'd love your input on the adjustments I made below.  To clarify, my Alpha.Range is a column ("only search column H for these keywords") and the data appears typically comma delimited "H54, H35.80, H69" could all be in one cell on a row.  So for instance, one of my search terms would be "H54".  @MathieuGuindon

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working - I adjusted @MathieuGuindon 's custom function to try clarify for myself the desired relationship between my search terms:  I have a set of search terms and I need to know when any of them appear in my data.

```
Public Function ContainsAny(ByVal data As String, ByVal caseSensitive _ 
    As Boolean, ParamArray searchterms() As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim k As Integer
    Dim found As Boolean

    For k = LBound(searchterms) To UBound(searchterms)
        found = Contains(data, CStr(searchterms(k)), caseSensitive)
        If found Then Exit For
    Next

    ContainsAny = found

End Function



Public Function Contains(ByVal data As String, ByVal searchterms _
    As String, Optional ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    Dim compareMethod As VbCompareMethod

    If caseSensitive Then
        compareMethod = vbBinaryCompare
    Else
        compareMethod = vbTextCompare
    End If

    Contains = (InStr(1, data, searchterms, compareMethod) <> 0)

End Function


'implemented as
Case ContainsAny(Alpha.Range("H" & i), False, "ABC", "123", "XYZ)
```