# Function for "Does Not Contain" (InStr()=0)

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a function harvested from user [Mathieu Guindon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43196497/11632049) that allows for quick checking of if any of a set of strings are contained in the cell without having to use `InStr() Or InStr() Or` etc. That part is working great, but I now need to adapt it to create another function that checks for if any of a set of strings are NOT contained in the cell also, and I can't get it to return the desired result.

I put in a series of dummies to check if the code is working as expected, and it appears the issue is when I ask my new function (`DoesNotContainAny`) to search for more than 1 string -- again, the `ContainsAny` function is working perfect.

```
ColF         ColG      Returned      Correct
H54          H54          False        False  
H54                        True         True  
L20, H54     H54          False        False  
B18          B18          False        False  
             B18           True         True  
L20, B18     B18           True        False    <-- issue
```

Thank you in advance for any wisdom or insight you can impart!!

```vb
'direct adapation of Mathieu's function
Public Function ContainsAny(ByVal data As String, ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean, ParamArray searchterms() As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim k As Integer
    Dim found As Boolean
    For k = LBound(searchterms) To UBound(searchterms)
        found = Contains(data, CStr(searchterms(k)), caseSensitive)
        If found Then Exit For
    Next
    ContainsAny = found
End Function

Public Function Contains(ByVal data As String, ByVal searchterms As String, Optional ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    Dim compareMethod As VbCompareMethod
    If caseSensitive Then
        compareMethod = vbBinaryCompare
    Else
        compareMethod = vbTextCompare
    End If
    Contains = (InStr(1, data, searchterms, compareMethod) <> 0)
End Function

'attempt at replicating the function to return true when none of the strings are found
Public Function DoesNotContainAny(ByVal data As String, ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean, ParamArray searchterms2() As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim n As Integer
    Dim notfound As Boolean
    For n = LBound(searchterms2) To UBound(searchterms2)
        notfound = DoesNotContain(data, CStr(searchterms2(n)), caseSensitive)
        If notfound Then Exit For
    Next
    DoesNotContainAny = notfound
End Function


Public Function DoesNotContain(ByVal data As String, ByVal searchterms2 As String, Optional ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    Dim compareMethod As VbCompareMethod
    If caseSensitive Then
        compareMethod = vbBinaryCompare
    Else
        compareMethod = vbTextCompare
    End If
    DoesNotContain = (InStr(1, data, searchterms2, compareMethod) = 0)
End Function


'applied within various If/Then/ElseIfs like this:
For i = 2 To LastRow

    'For each row, return True if Columns F&G don't match AND that Col G contains H54 AND that Col F does NOT contain H54 
    If PCPJ.Range("F" & i) <> PCPJ.Range("G" & i) And _
        (ContainsAny(PCPJ.Range("G" & i), False, "H54") And DoesNotContainAny(PCPJ.Range("F" & i), False, "H54")) Then

            'Check for duplicate UniqueID in CoderBook Referrals sheet to avoid copying duplicate rows
            DuplicateCheck = Application.Match(PCPJ.Range("R" & i).Value, Referral.Columns(18), 0)
            If IsError(DuplicateCheck) Then
                'If no matches are found on UniqueID, then copy appropriate rows to CoderBook Referrals sheet
                Referral.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value = PCPJ.Rows(i).Value
            End If

    'For each row, return True if Columns F&G don't match AND that Col G contains B17 or B18 AND that Col F does NOT contain B17 or B18
    ElseIf PCPJ.Range("F" & i) <> PCPJ.Range("G" & i) And _
        (ContainsAny(PCPJ.Range("G" & i), False, "B17", "B18") And _
     DoesNotContainAny(PCPJ.Range("F" & i), False, "B17", "B18")) Then

            DuplicateCheck = Application.Match(PCPJ.Range("R" & i).Value, Referrals.Columns(18), 0)
            If IsError(DuplicateCheck) Then
                Referrals.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value = PCPJ.Rows(i).Value
            End If

    'Etc...
```

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is `Not InStr() AND Not InStr() AND Not...`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks for your reply, however, the goal is to create a function that allows me to avoid having to list a ton of repeating InStr() functions - this is a small piece of my code, where I'm often asking it to search for 20-30 strings at a time for a given criteria - that part works great.  The trouble I'm having is figuring out why the unexpected result was returned for the last test case.

Comment: So you want a function called `ContainsAll` and you want to call it as `If Not ContainsAll(...) Then`. For which you take `ContainsAny`, put `found = True` before the `For` loop and replace the `If found Then Exit For` with `If Not found Then Exit For`.

Comment: Thanks @GSerg for the format edit - still getting the hang of things!

Comment: @GSerg The `ContainsAny` function and desired `DoesNotContainAny` function must be in the same `If` statement, as they are checks on a single criteria.  E.g.  the code checks that ColF&G don't match, and then checks if ColG contains a desired string, and then must check if ColF does not contain the desired string, which would result in a true meeting of the criteria. It seems to be working for criteria where I'm only searching for 1 string, but when I ask the `DoesNotContainAny` to search for multiple, it's returning undesired results

Comment: @maclee It does not matter if they are in the same `If` condition or not. What is confusing is exactly what your new function must do. Is it `ContainsNoneOfThose` or `DoesNotContainSome`?

Comment: @GSerg I am trying to make my `DoesNotContainAny` a function that returns true if none of the listed substrings are found.  E.g. from the code `DoesNotContainAny(PCPJ.Range("F" & i), False, "B17", "B18")` returns true when neither B17 nor B18 are found in the string

Comment: Then why do you need another function for that, if this result is the direct opposite of `ContainsAny` that you already have? `If ContainsAny(PCPJ.Range("G" & i), False, "B17", "B18") And Not ContainsAny(PCPJ.Range("F" & i), False, "B17", "B18")`.

Comment: @GSerg You are absolutely right, I guess I just got so focused on it I hadn't thought about it that way!  Making it way harder that I needed to. Thank you for sticking with me through that!!

Comment: @GSerg would you mind throwing that in an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DoesNotContainAny` is a confusing name. It may not be immediately clear what it determines: that a string has only some of the options, but not all, or that a string has exactly none of the options.

Such is the fate of functions that are named with [negative sense](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070314-00/?p=27623).

Using positive sense, you would call that function `LacksSome()` for the former case or `ContainsNone()` for the latter.
You would then notice that `LacksSome()` is still named in the negative sense, and you would devise an opposite function, `ContainsAll()`, which is finally named fully positively, and which you would call as `Not ContainsAll()` to mean "lacks at least one".

Going about implementing `ContainsAll()`, you would notice that you can easily get it from the existing `ContainsAny()` by changing one line and adding another:

```vb
' Former ContainsAny
Public Function ContainsAll(ByVal data As String, ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean, ParamArray searchterms() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim found As Boolean

    found = True  ' Added
    For k = LBound(searchterms) To UBound(searchterms)
        found = Contains(data, CStr(searchterms(k)), caseSensitive)
        If Not found Then Exit For  ' Changed
    Next
    ContainsAny = found
End Function
```

Going about implementing `ContainsNone()`, you would notice that "contains none" means "does not contain any", and you already have `ContainsAny()`, so instead of defining a separate function, you would call `Not ContainsAny()`.